# Need help understanding discrete mathematics logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I am having a heck of a time understanding Discrete Mathematics. I have tried this myself and put my answer below. If anyone could help me if my answer is incorrect could you please explain to me what I have done wrong? I really need to understand this.

Here is the question:

Translate the given statement into propositional logic using the propositions provided:

```
You can upgrade your operating system only if you have a 32-bit processor
running at 1 GHz or faster, at least 1 GB RAM, and 16 GB free hard disk space,
or a 64- bit processor running at 2 GHz or faster, at least 2 GB RAM,
and at least 32 GB free hard disk space.
```

Express you answer in terms of:

- `u:   You can upgrade your operating system`
- `b32: You have a 32-bit processor`
- `b64: You have a 64-bit processor`
- `g1:  Your processor runs at 1 GHz or faster`
- `g2:  Your processor runs at 2 GHz or faster`
- `r1:  Your processor has at least 1 GB RAM`
- `r2:  Your processor has at least 2 GB RAM`
- `h16: You have at least 16 GB free hard disk space`
- `h32: You have at least 32 GB free hard disk space`

Here is my answer:

$u ↔ ((b32 ∧ r1 ∧ h16) ∨ (b64 ∧ g2 ∧ r2 ∧ h32) )$

Comment: Yes, you need to replacy $\iff$ with $\rightarrow$, then all is good.

Comment: Ok thanks. "running at" really through me off. I wasn't sure if it should be an "and", but thats all that made sense to me.

Comment: Am I the only one noticing `g1` is missing in the 32-bit clause?

Comment: You're right, @Lord_Farin.

Comment: @Lord_Farin, thanks, I fixed it on my side. Stupid errors kill me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @GitGud in a comment, your only mistake is with the $\iff$.

Your logical statement is equivalent to:

```
You can upgrade your operating system only if
you have a 32-bit processor running at 1 GHz or faster, at least 1 GB RAM,
and 16 GB free hard disk space, or a 64- bit processor running at 2 GHz or
faster, at least 2 GB RAM, and at least 32 GB free hard disk space.
```

**AND**

```
You have a 32-bit processor running at 1 GHz or faster, at least 1 GB RAM,
and 16 GB free hard disk space, or a 64- bit processor running at 2 GHz or
faster, at least 2 GB RAM, and at least 32 GB free hard disk space,
only if you can upgrade your operating system.
```

You can correct this error by changing the $\iff$ to $\implies$.

Comment: @Ducksauce88: Oh... you just changed it in the question. This makes my answer obsolete.

Comment: its ok. i really appreciate it!

Comment: @Ducksauce88: You're welcome :) ... But perhaps you should revert the question to its original version, so that other users can learn from this post in the future.